# what are these arrow operators in context free grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I'm studying context free grammar and I'm curious what the arrow with the star and the arrow without the star mean in parts f and g where:

- f is false.
- g is true.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"x ⇒ y" means that y can be derived from x in exactly one application of some production of the grammar.  Putting an asterisk over the ⇒ means that y is derived from x via zero or more (but finitely many!) applications of some sequence of productions.

Comment: so f is false because i cant obtain aba by running through this sequence once (which makes sense) but arrow* is correct because i can first get ab, then a in the second pass?

Comment: @jfisk: Almost; the full sequence for g is T ⇒ XTX ⇒ aTX ⇒ aTa ⇒ aXa ⇒ aba (among other possible orders of events).

Answer (score 3):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Repetitive_rule_application for an explanation.

That is to say, if u star-arrow v, there is some series of applications of rules that goes from u to v.